# bootstrap 4 align buttons in center

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

im a little stuck as to how to center align a button group i have:

```
<section>
  <div class="d-inline mx-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried to add d-inline and mx-auto to it but it doesnt work. Im not that familiar with the library so could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `margin:auto` its working with bootstrap 4

```css
.center{margin:auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="row">
  <div class="center">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

or you can use `mx-auto` in this way..

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="row">
  <div class="mx-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! just out of curiosity, why would `mx-auto` work in this case?

Comment: you can use `mx-auto` but you need to add `row` class to its parent

Answer (score 3):

add the 2 classes `mx-auto d-block` to the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block">My Button</button>
```

this worked for me when the button was in a card-body div.

Comment: Worked for me in a non card-body div as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By default bootstrap give `text-center` class. Please add this. Extra css or class haven't needed.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert class `center` :

```
<div class="d-inline mx-auto center">
```

And:

```
 .d-inline.mx-auto.center {
    text-align: center!important;
    display:block!important;
}
```

```css
.d-inline.mx-auto.center {
    text-align:center!important;
    display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section>
  <div class="d-inline mx-auto center">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: this works like a charm, just im using bootstrap 4, if there isnt any other way, ill just downgrade to 3

Comment: @Znaneswar , see updated post, i insert class `center`.

Answer (score 0):

Different way to also try it, to parent element `text-align: center`
example:

```
.center { text-align: center; }
```

TRY THIS CSS

```
<section>
    <div class="center">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
     </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that:
just add: `style="margin-left: 45%;"`

```
<section>
  <div class="d-inline mx-auto" style="margin-left: 45%;">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Traffic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">MAC Monitoring</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Alert Logging</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Diameter Server</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Maintenance Mode</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a quick landing page and wanted the button centered. Adding a div was a simple solution for me :)

Learn more

[My page in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7ooj.png)

Comment: consider explaining your answer a bit more to help the poster and others understand exactly what you did that worked, and why it is applicable here.